# Consume Dynamics CRM Web API directly into PostgreSQL database in Django web app

Tags: javascript, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM has most current client and company data and I need it for the internal database the frequently uses the data. Trying to replace duplicative databases where one is getting updated (CRM) and the other is not.

Because it is Office 365 and hosted in the cloud, we don't have access to the database, just are able to use the Web API. The Web API is over an HTTPS connection and requires login credentials.

One thought was to use a PostgreSQL FDW like `www_fdw`, which is great except it accepts no options for login credentials. There does not appear to be alternatives.

So I am back to using Django, Python, and/or Javascript to get the JSON, de-serialize it, and import it into the database.

I do not need to display it in a Django template. Really, it just needs to come from CRM and go directly into the database. I am just not sure the best way to handle it.

For example, would the Django REST Framework make it easier than just using JavaScript and Python to request the Web API and de-serialize? From there, how is written to the database if it is bypassing Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an intermediate web service, with no auth, available only in local domain. Postgre would call the WS, and the WS would call CRM using standard SDK techniques. You can use the methods described here: [Unable to add a service reference to Dynamics 365 crm in visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740915/unable-to-add-a-service-reference-to-dynamics-365-crm-in-visual-studio-2012/42227392#42227392)

The WEB Api is very limited in functionality and very hard to set up (security wise). In my opinion the effort is not worth it, if you can have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a logic app with a Dynamics 365 connector to PostgreSQL.  There's a sample in the link below :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-crmonline